# How do run a query within a sqlalchemy hybird expression?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Have a class Run that has a "has many" relationship to a class Tag.
I need to be able to filter runs based on a function of the tags (tag_collection).

Below is a snippet of my code.  In this case I am using the automapper, but I don't think that matters too much.

```
Base = automap_base()

class Run(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'runs'
    macro_id = Column(ForeignKey('macros.id'))  

    @hybrid_property
    def tag_count(self):
        return(len(self.tag_collection))

    @hybrid_property
    def default_region(self):
        return(reduce(lambda  memo, t: memo or t.name == "region" and t.value == "default", self.tag_collection, False))

    @default_region.expression
    def default_region(cls):
        # how do I do the query here?

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    run_id = Column(ForeignKey('runs.id'))
```

If I get an instance of a Run,  I can make use of the `default_region` property, but when I run a query, and try to filter using the `default_region` property, I either get the Run class passed in (as self) in the `@hybird_property` decorated `default_region` method or I end up in the `@default_region.expression` decorated `default_region` method,  which also receives the Run class.

Example query:

```
session.query(Run).filter(Run.default_region == True).all()
```

I think I need to do a query in the `@default_region.expression` decorated `default_region` method, but I don't see how to get a handle on the session.  I know about `Session.object_session(someobject)`,  but I think `someobject` needs to be an instance of the orm class not the class itself.

I think I am either completely wrong about my methodology of the filtering, or I need to somehow get a handle to the session object in that `@default_region.expression` decorated `default_region` method.

Is there a better way to accomplish this filtering?

How do a get the session in the`@default_region.expression` decorated `default_region` method?

Comment: So `default_region` is true when there is a row in `tags` with the right `runs.id` foreign key, and `name` set to `region` and `value` set to `default`?

Comment: yes,  I probably will have other "connivence" methods like this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me to be a [*Correlated Subquery Relationship Hybrid*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid). When `Run.default_region` is added as a filter, you want to update the query to add

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tags
    WHERE run_id = runs.id
      AND name = "region"
      AND value = "default")
```

Return that as an expression, with the [`exists()` function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists, and_

@default_region.expression
def default_region(cls):
    return exists([1]).where(and_(
        Tag.run_id == cls.id,
        Tag.name == 'region',
        Tag.value == 'default'))
```

Note that you want to *avoid* using `== True` or `== False` here, there is no need! Just use the property directly:

```
session.query(Run).filter(Run.default_region).all()
```

or use `~` to negate:

```
session.query(Run).filter(~Run.default_region).all()
```

By defining the [`.expression` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property.expression) for the property, you have told SQLAlchemy to use that method when accessing the property on the class, so the context is *always the class* there. Without defining `.exists` (or a [`.comparator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_property.comparator)), `Run.default_region` would call the `default_region` getter (the method decorated with `@hybrid_property) as a class method, so only then would that method have to then work with either an instance *or* a class being passed in. For some hybrid property implementations, that happens to work by virtue of how they use attributes on the context.

As for the implementation of the `default_region` *instance* property, I'd not use `reduce()` there; use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
@hybrid_property
def default_region(self):
    return any(
        t.name == "region" and t.value == "default"
        for t in self.tag_collection)
```

`any()` stops iterating over the supplied generator expression when a match has been found.

Comment: This seems to work fine.  I figured I did not need the == True (I added it at some point trying to debug things),  and yes I had not seen any(), seems like the way to go.   I think part of my problem with this, is it's not clear to me that _context_ of the @default_region.expression decorated default_region method is. If possible, could you add that to your answer?

Comment: @nPn: the `@default_region.expression` is always passed the class. It is only used when you use `Run.default_region`, so accessing the name of the property *on the class*, a use that only applies to building expressions (such as in `.filter(Run.default_region)` and `.filter(~Run.default_region)`. If you *don't* define the `.expression` method, then SQLAlchemy would fall back to the `@hybrid_property`-decorated method, at which point the class is passed in instead of the instance.

Comment: @nPn: put differently: by using `.expression` you made it possible to separate the instance and class context cases.

Comment: Right, I got that part (separating instance and class) .  If I have this right,  the .expression decorated method requires you to return and sql expression that will be executed later as part of the overall query,  while the @hybrid_property decorated expression simply runs in the context of the object.  I was trying to force the .expression to do the actual query and return values, rather than simply return the expression.

Comment: @nPn: exactly; you return an expression that can be a part of a larger query expression. See it as a hook to provide the expression for the  `Class.hybrid_property_name` *placeholder* in any SQLAlchemy ORM expression.